# Visual Studio 2010 Installer Project Works on Windows 7, but not Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-8

I've recently developed a Windows app using Visual Studio 2010, programmed using Visual C++. This is the first app that I've made for Windows in a very long time.

I've added an installer to the project, which contains the primary output of the app project and a Word document containing the user guide. This installer works fine on my machine, and on some of my colleagues' machines.

However, my boss now wants to test the app before we send it to our customers. He's tried to install it on his machine, which runs Windows 8, and he can't find the app!

Is there some incompatibility between Windows 7 and Windows 8 that could be causing this?

Comment: Did you install the [c++ redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=5555)?

Comment: Yeah I have the C++ redistributable installed. I think I was just missing shortcuts to the Applications directory and Desktop.

Comment: No, I haven't actually fixed it, it still won't show up in the start menu!